# Problemas al enviar Intent y recibirlo

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicaciones y estoy teniendo un problema.
Estoy pasando el nombre de usuario con un intent desde una actividad a otra, y cuando lo recibo en la segunda actividad, no me muestra nada.
Les paso una captura de mi codigo.
Gracias!! :D[image: La primera imagen es de la primera actividad, y la segunda en donde quiero recibir el intent.]

Comment: copia el codigo como texto para que sea mas facil ayudar y quita las imagenes.

Comment: Agregando al comentario de Ramiro, has esto por medio del botón de `editar` en tu pregunta, te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta asegurarte de que el dato que vas a pasar esté en el formato deseado, en esta caso string y en la segunda actividad asegúrate que el objeto bundle tiene dicha información.

Sería de ayuda para las proximas preguntas que el código que subes a stackoverflow sea editable y no una imagen.

Primera Actividad

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var etName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
        if (etName.text.toString() != ""){
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("NAME", etName.text.toString())
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

Segunda Actividad

```
    class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        var tvName = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

        val bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
        if (bundle!=null){
            val name = bundle.getString("NAME") // 1
            tvName.text = name.toString()
        }
    }
}
```